# Modify XML: attributes into elements

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I have an `XML` column that contains data with similar structure:

```xml
<Root>
    <Elements>
        <Element Code="1" Value="aaa"></Element>
        <Element Code="2" Value="bbb"></Element>
        <Element Code="3" Value="ccc"></Element>
    </Elements>
</Root>
```

How can I modify the data using SQL Server to change each `Value` attribute into an element?

```xml
<Root>
    <Elements>
        <Element Code="1">
            <Value>aaa</Value>
        </Element>
        <Element Code="2">
            <Value>bbb</Value>
        </Element>
        <Element Code="3">
            <Value>ccc</Value>
        </Element>
    </Elements>
</Root>
```

**Update:**

My XML looks more like this:

```xml
<Root attr1="val1" attr2="val2">
    <Elements>
        <Element Code="1" Value="aaa" ExtraData="extra" />
        <Element Code="2" Value="bbb" ExtraData="extra" />
        <Element Code="3" Value="ccc" ExtraData="extra" />
        <Element Code="4" Value="" ExtraData="extra" />
        <Element Code="5" ExtraData="extra" />
    </Elements>
    <ExtraData>
       <!-- Some XML is here -->
    </ExtraData>
</Root>
```

I would like only to move `Value` attribute and preserve all other attributes and elements.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the first place? I can't think of any benefit to this unless you plan on having multiple `<Value>` elements per each `<Element>`. If not, then moving the attribute to an element just makes for more bloated, and possibly less efficient, XML.

Comment: @srutzky, it's a part of a refactoring. The second step is storing complex data inside `<Value>` element or instead of it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can shred the XML and rebuild it again using XQuery.

```sql
declare @X xml = '
<Root attr1="val1" attr2="val2">
    <Elements>
        <Element Code="1" Value="aaa" ExtraData="extra" />
        <Element Code="2" Value="" ExtraData="extra" />
        <Element Code="3" ExtraData="extra" />
    </Elements>
    <ExtraData>
       <!-- Some XML is here -->
    </ExtraData>
</Root>';

select @X.query('
  (: Create element Root :)
  element Root 
    {
      (: Add all attributes from Root to Root :)
      /Root/@*, 
      (: create element Elements under Root :)
      element Elements 
        {
          (: For each Element element in /Root/Elements :)
          for $e in /Root/Elements/Element
          return 
            (: Add element Element :)
            element Element 
              {
                (: Add all attributes except Value to Element :)
                $e/@*[local-name() != "Value"], 

                (: Check if Attribute Value exist :)
                if (data($e/@Value) != "")
                then
                  (: Create a Value element under Element :)
                  element Value 
                  {
                    (: Add attribute Value as data to the element Element :)
                    data($e/@Value)
                  }
                else () (: Empty element :)
              } 
          },
      (: Add all childelements to Root except the Elements element :)
      /Root/*[local-name() != "Elements"]
    }');
```

Result:

```xml
<Root attr1="val1" attr2="val2">
  <Elements>
    <Element Code="1" ExtraData="extra">
      <Value>aaa</Value>
    </Element>
    <Element Code="2" ExtraData="extra" />
    <Element Code="3" ExtraData="extra" />
  </Elements>
  <ExtraData>
    <!-- Some XML is here -->
  </ExtraData>
</Root>
```

If `Elements` is not the first element under `Root` the query need to be modified to add all elements before `Elements` first and all elements after `Elements` after.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the methods of the XML datatype (eg [modify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187093.aspx)) and some XQuery to modify the xml, eg

```
DECLARE @x XML = '<Root attr1="val1" attr2="val2">
    <Elements>
        <Element Code="1" Value="aaa" ExtraData="extra" />
        <Element Code="2" Value="bbb" ExtraData="extra" />
        <Element Code="3" Value="ccc" ExtraData="extra" />
    </Elements>
    <ExtraData>
       <!-- Some XML is here -->
    </ExtraData>
</Root>'


SELECT 'before' s, DATALENGTH(@x) dl, @x x

-- Add 'Value' element to each Element which doesn't already have one
DECLARE @i INT = 0

WHILE @x.exist('Root/Elements/Element[not(Value)]') = 1
BEGIN

    SET @x.modify( 'insert element Value {data(Root/Elements/Element[not(Value)]/@Value)[1]} into (Root/Elements/Element[not(Value)])[1]' )

    SET @i += 1

    IF @i > 99 BEGIN RAISERROR( 'Too many loops...', 16, 1 ) BREAK END

END

-- Now delete all Value attributes
SET @x.modify('delete Root/Elements/Element/@Value' )

SELECT 'after' s, DATALENGTH(@x) dl, @x x
```

This method doesn't tend to scale well over large pieces of XML but might suit you better than a wholesale replacement of the XML.

You can also easily adapt this method if your XML is stored in a table.  Again from experience I would not recommend running a single update against a million row table.  If your table is large, consider running a cursor through it or otherwise batching the updates.  Here's the technique:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( rowId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, yourXML XML )

INSERT INTO @t ( yourXML )
SELECT '<Root attr1="val1" attr2="val2">
    <Elements>
        <Element Code="1" Value="aaa" ExtraData="extra" />
        <Element Code="2" Value="bbb" ExtraData="extra" />
        <Element Code="3" Value="ccc" ExtraData="extra" />
    </Elements>
    <ExtraData>
       <!-- Some XML is here -->
    </ExtraData>
</Root>'

INSERT INTO @t ( yourXML )
SELECT '<Root attr1="val1" attr2="val2">
    <Elements>
        <Element Code="21" Value="uuu" ExtraData="extra" />
        <Element Code="22" Value="vvv" ExtraData="extra" />
        <Element Code="23" Value="www" ExtraData="extra" />
        <Element Code="24" Value="xxx" ExtraData="extra" />
        <Element Code="25" Value="yyy" ExtraData="extra" />
        <Element Code="26" Value="zzz" ExtraData="extra" />
    </Elements>
    <ExtraData>
       <!-- Some XML is here -->
    </ExtraData>
</Root>'


SELECT 'before' s, DATALENGTH(yourXML) dl, yourXML
FROM @t 

-- Add 'Value' element to each Element which doesn't already have one
DECLARE @i INT = 0

WHILE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM @t WHERE yourXML.exist('Root/Elements/Element[not(Value)]') = 1 )
BEGIN

    UPDATE @t
    SET yourXML.modify( 'insert element Value {data(Root/Elements/Element[not(Value)]/@Value)[1]} into (Root/Elements/Element[not(Value)])[1]' )

    SET @i += 1

    IF @i > 99 BEGIN RAISERROR( 'Too many loops...', 16, 1 ) BREAK END

END

-- Now delete all Value attributes
UPDATE @t
SET yourXML.modify('delete Root/Elements/Element/@Value' )

SELECT 'after' s, DATALENGTH(yourXML) dl, yourXML
FROM @t
```

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:**

I have updated the code, as well as the input and output XML in the example query below to reflect the latest requirement, stated in a comment on @Mikael's fine [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/120074/30859), which is:

> to not create Value element if @Value is empty or doesn't exist

While a single expression can correctly match this new variation, there does not appear to be a way to omit the empty `<Value/>` element in a single pass since conditional logic is not allowed in the replacement string. So, I have adapted this to be a 2 part modification: one pass to get the non-empty `@Value` attributes and one pass to get the empty `@Value` attributes.  There was no need to handle `<Element>`s missing the `@Value` attribute since the desire is to not have the `<Value>` element anyway.

---

One option is to treat the XML as a regular string and transform it based on a pattern. This is easily accomplished using Regular Expressions (specifically the "Replace" function) which can be made available via SQLCLR code.

The example below uses the **RegEx_Replace** scalar UDF from the [SQL#](http://SQLsharp.com/) library (which I am the author of, but this RegEx function is available in the Free version, along with many others):

```sql
DECLARE @SomeXml XML;
SET @SomeXml = N'<Root attr1="val1" attr2="val2">
    <Elements>
        <Element Code="1" Value="aaa" ExtraData="extra1" />
        <Element Code="22" Value="bbb" ExtraData="extra2" />
        <Element Code="333" Value="ccc" ExtraData="extra3" />
        <Element Code="4444" Value="" ExtraData="extra4" />
        <Element Code="55555" ExtraData="extra5" />
    </Elements>
    <ExtraData>
       <Something Val="1">qwerty A</Something>
       <Something Val="2">qwerty B</Something>
    </ExtraData>
</Root>';

DECLARE @TempStringOfXml NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Expression NVARCHAR(4000),
        @Replacement NVARCHAR(4000);


SET @TempStringOfXml = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @SomeXml);
PRINT N'Original: ' + @TempStringOfXml;

---

SET @Expression =
              N'(<Element Code="[^"]+")\s+Value="([^"]+)"\s+(ExtraData="[^"]+")\s*/>';
SET @Replacement = N'$1 $3><Value>$2</Value></Element>';

SELECT @TempStringOfXml = SQL#.RegEx_Replace(@TempStringOfXml, @Expression,
                                             @Replacement, -1, 1, '');

PRINT '-------------------------------------';
PRINT N'Phase 1:  ' + @TempStringOfXml; -- transform Elements with a non-empty @Value

---

SET @Expression = N'(<Element Code="[^"]+")\s+Value=""\s+(ExtraData="[^"]+")\s*/>';
SET @Replacement = N'$1 $2 />';

SELECT @TempStringOfXml = SQL#.RegEx_Replace(@TempStringOfXml, @Expression,
                                             @Replacement, -1, 1, '');

PRINT '-------------------------------------';
PRINT N'Phase 2:  ' + @TempStringOfXml; -- transform Elements with an empty @Value

SELECT CONVERT(XML, @TempStringOfXml); -- prove that this is valid XML
```

The `PRINT` statements are in there just to make for easier side-by-side comparison in the "Messages" tab. The resulting output is (I modified the original XML a little to make it very clear that only the desired parts were touched and nothing else):

```
Original: <Root attr1="val1" attr2="val2"><Elements><Element Code="1" Value="aaa" ExtraData="extra1"/><Element Code="22" Value="bbb" ExtraData="extra2"/><Element Code="333" Value="ccc" ExtraData="extra3"/><Element Code="4444" Value="" ExtraData="extra4"/><Element Code="55555" ExtraData="extra5"/></Elements><ExtraData><Something Val="1">qwerty A</Something><Something Val="2">qwerty B</Something></ExtraData></Root>
-------------------------------------
Phase 1:  <Root attr1="val1" attr2="val2"><Elements><Element Code="1" ExtraData="extra1"><Value>aaa</Value></Element><Element Code="22" ExtraData="extra2"><Value>bbb</Value></Element><Element Code="333" ExtraData="extra3"><Value>ccc</Value></Element><Element Code="4444" Value="" ExtraData="extra4"/><Element Code="55555" ExtraData="extra5"/></Elements><ExtraData><Something Val="1">qwerty A</Something><Something Val="2">qwerty B</Something></ExtraData></Root>
-------------------------------------
Phase 2:  <Root attr1="val1" attr2="val2"><Elements><Element Code="1" ExtraData="extra1"><Value>aaa</Value></Element><Element Code="22" ExtraData="extra2"><Value>bbb</Value></Element><Element Code="333" ExtraData="extra3"><Value>ccc</Value></Element><Element Code="4444" ExtraData="extra4" /><Element Code="55555" ExtraData="extra5"/></Elements><ExtraData><Something Val="1">qwerty A</Something><Something Val="2">qwerty B</Something></ExtraData></Root>
```

If you want to update a field in a table, you can adapt the above to be the following:

```sql
DECLARE @NonEmptyValueExpression NVARCHAR(4000),
        @NonEmptyValueReplacement NVARCHAR(4000),
        @EmptyValueExpression NVARCHAR(4000),
        @EmptyValueReplacement NVARCHAR(4000);

SET @NonEmptyValueExpression =
                   N'(<Element Code="[^"]+")\s+Value="([^"]+)"\s+(ExtraData="[^"]+")\s*/>';
SET @NonEmptyValueReplacement = N'$1 $3><Value>$2</Value></Element>';

SET @EmptyValueExpression =
                   N'(<Element Code="[^"]+")\s+Value=""\s+(ExtraData="[^"]+")\s*/>';
SET @EmptyValueReplacement = N'$1 $2 />';

UPDATE tbl
SET    XmlField = SQL#.RegEx_Replace4k(
                                     SQL#.RegEx_Replace4k(
                                                     CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), tbl.XmlField),
                                                        @NonEmptyValueExpression,
                                                        @NonEmptyValueReplacement,
                                                        -1, 1, ''),
                                     @EmptyValueExpression,
                                     @EmptyValueReplacement,
                                     -1, 1, '')
FROM   SchemaName.TableName tbl
WHERE  tbl.XmlField.exist('Root/Elements/Element/@Value') = 1;
```

Comment: your solution looks good and it was helpful but I'can use CLR.

Comment: @Wojteq Thanks. It's good to have options, right? Just out of curiosity, why are you not able to use SQLCLR?

Comment: It's because of our architecture. We've got multi-tenancy web application. Every tenant has its own database. We do not want to add any other 'moving part' that can fail during i.e. deployment process. Using code-only/webapp-only approach is much more maintainable for us.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably better ways of doing it outside of SQL Server.
However, here is one way of doing it.

> Your data:

```
declare @xml xml = N'<Root>
    <Elements>
        <Element Code="1" Value="aaa"></Element>
        <Element Code="2" Value="bbb"></Element>
        <Element Code="3" Value="ccc"></Element>
    </Elements>
</Root>';
```

> Query:

```
With xml as (
    Select 
        Code = x.e.value('(@Code)', 'varchar(10)')
        , Value = x.e.value('(@Value)', 'varchar(10)')
    From @xml.nodes('/Root//Elements/Element') as x(e)
)
Select * From (
    Select code
        , (
        Select value
        From xml x1 where x1.Code = Element.Code
        For xml path(''), elements, type
    )
    From xml Element
    For xml auto, type
) as Root(Elements)
for xml auto, elements;
```

The xml CTE transform your xml variable into a table.

The main select then transforms the CTE back into xml.

> Output:

```
<Root>
  <Elements>
    <Element code="1">
      <value>aaa</value>
    </Element>
    <Element code="2">
      <value>bbb</value>
    </Element>
    <Element code="3">
      <value>ccc</value>
    </Element>
  </Elements>
</Root>
```

It can also be done using `For XML Explicit`.

Comment: Thank you for your help however I've updated my question - my case is move complex. I'd like to update my XML using SQL Server because of performance. I've got tables that contain hundreds of thousands records. The other alternative is to load it, deserialize and serialize it inside ASP MVC application.